# KDE Default Profile

Tags: kde

I'm configuring a CentOS 5.5 workstation with a default desktop environment of KDE 3.5 that will have several users. I set up a test account, and I have the account configured exactly how I want the other user accounts configured with respect to the user profile.  How can I make it to where when a new user is created and that user logs in for the first time, they will have a profile exactly like the one I've set up now?  I'm not concerned whether or not they change it later.

Answer (score 1):

You want a *skel* directory, see [man 8 adduser](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser).

Comment: I thought of this.  Can I just add the contents of my already-customized-user's .kde directory to /etc/skel?

Comment: [TITS](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=545998)

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found [kioskadmin](http://extragear.kde.org/apps/kiosktool/), which seems to be ideal for creating a locked down multi-user desktop.  That's not really what I'm looking for in this case and my user base is not large at all, so I think I will just manually copy the hidden settings to the user's home dir manually (~/.kde, etc).